# Post title is duplicating if have_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post, while-loop, duplicates

I am trying to add some post titles from a custom post category. I currently have it printing the correct amount of `<li>` but unfortunately it is the same name. You will see I narrow it down using meta, so I am getting 5 results all the same name.

I do not pretend to be a pro at this, so I am humbly asking for any help that the community may have.

Thanks In advance.

I have tried doing a foreach and also doing the if have_posts. both have yielded the same result.

```
$page_title = get_the_title();

$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post_type' => 'person',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'division',
        'meta_value' => 'Singles'
    );

    $string = '';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        $string .= '<ul>';
            while( $query->have_posts() ):
                $query->the_post();
                $string .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            endwhile;
        $string .= '</ul>';
            echo $string;
            wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    // No, we don't have any posts, so maybe we display a nice message
    echo "<p class='no-posts'>" . __( "Sorry, there are no posts at this time." ) . "</p>";
    endif;
```

So what we are going for is looking for how many posts exist in "Singles" (in my case that is 5) and printing the post title for each one in an `<li>`. Currently it prints 1 of the 5, 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

[get_the_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) has the following implementation

```
function get_the_title( $post = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    $title = isset( $post->post_title ) ? $post->post_title : '';
    $id    = isset( $post->ID ) ? $post->ID : 0;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( ! empty( $post->post_password ) ) {

            /**
             * Filters the text prepended to the post title for protected posts.
             *
             * The filter is only applied on the front end.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @param string  $prepend Text displayed before the post title.
             *                         Default 'Protected: %s'.
             * @param WP_Post $post    Current post object.
             */
            $protected_title_format = apply_filters( 'protected_title_format', __( 'Protected: %s' ), $post );
            $title                  = sprintf( $protected_title_format, $title );
        } elseif ( isset( $post->post_status ) && 'private' == $post->post_status ) {

            /**
             * Filters the text prepended to the post title of private posts.
             *
             * The filter is only applied on the front end.
             *
             * @since 2.8.0
             *
             * @param string  $prepend Text displayed before the post title.
             *                         Default 'Private: %s'.
             * @param WP_Post $post    Current post object.
             */
            $private_title_format = apply_filters( 'private_title_format', __( 'Private: %s' ), $post );
            $title                = sprintf( $private_title_format, $title );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters the post title.
     *
     * @since 0.71
     *
     * @param string $title The post title.
     * @param int    $id    The post ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );
}
```

As you can see you can pass a post to it and then it will get its title. Since you didn't pass a post to it, it didn't get a title for you. Suggestion:

```
$page_title = get_the_title();

$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'post_type' => 'person',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'division',
        'meta_value' => 'Singles'
    );

    $string = '';
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ):
        $string .= '<ul>';
            while( $query->have_posts() ):
                $string .= '<li>' . get_the_title($query->the_post()) . '</li>';
            endwhile;
        $string .= '</ul>';
            echo $string;
            wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    // No, we don't have any posts, so maybe we display a nice message
    echo "<p class='no-posts'>" . __( "Sorry, there are no posts at this time." ) . "</p>";
    endif;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It actually yielded the same result. It is indeed printing the post title for me. The issue is it is printing the same post title 5 times. There is 5 posts in the meta value we are looking in. It is returning 1 of the 5 and printing that 1, 5 different times. Your code yielded the same result as my original unfortunately